# Flutter - can't get status bar height for accurate calculation of available screen height

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a test app that contains 2 widgets in a column.

The first should occupy 0.2 of the available height, and the second should occupy 0.8 of the available height. The latter is a scrollable widget.

In order to calculate the available height, I need 3 properties: screen height, status bar height, and appbar height.

I got screen height and appbar height.

From extensive search, I should be able to get status bar height with mediaQuery.padding.top, however it returns 0. Any idea why?

Currently, the bottom is overflowed by 24 pixels, which is clearly the status bar's height.

```
var availableHeight = mediaQuery.size.height - mediaQuery.padding.top - appBar.preferredSize.height; //737 - 0 - 56
```

I'm testing it in the android emulator on windows. Device: Pixel 3, OS: Android Pie.

I realized I can do this out of the box with LayoutBuilder without having to manually calculate the available height, but I'm still interested in the answer.

Here's the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(title: Text("Test"));

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        body: SafeArea(child: Test(appBar))
      )
    );
  }

}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  final AppBar appBar;

  Test(this.appBar);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var availableHeight = mediaQuery.size.height - mediaQuery.padding.top - appBar.preferredSize.height; //737 - 0 - 56

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: availableHeight * 0.2,
        ),
        Container(
          height: availableHeight * 0.8,
          child: getScrollable()
        )
      ]
    );
  }

  Widget getScrollable() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 600.0
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 600.0
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to calculate anything. Use `Flex` and `Flexible` to define how much space each child should take in relation to the space available:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(title: Text("Test"));

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        body: SafeArea(child: Test(appBar))
      )
    );
  }

}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  final AppBar appBar;

  Test(this.appBar);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 8,
          child: getScrollable(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getScrollable() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 600.0
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 600.0
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this flex solution seems more elegant than the one with LayoutBuilder which I briefly referred to in my question.
However, do you by any chance have a straightforward answer to the question?

"I realized I can do this out of the box with LayoutBuilder without having to manually calculate the available height, but I'm still interested in the answer."